# Google Calendar Event creation

Tags: calendar, timezone, google-calendar-api

How to create a Google Calendar event for UK Time zone by modifying the below url?

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20170504T110000Z/20170504T170000Z&location=Tatooine&text=Star+Wars+Day+Party&details=May+the+force+be+with+you
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timezone will be A.  I have changed the dates

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20170504T110000A/20170504T170000A&location=Tatooine&text=Star+Wars+Day+Party&details=May+the+force+be+with+you